# Processing Mouse Coordinates on Translated Shape

Tags: java, matrix, processing

I have a problem and can't seem to find a definite answer.

I have a grid, that I have transformed and rotated in 3D space.

```
translate(width-(width/2), 0);
rotateX(radians(30));
rotateZ(radians(60));
for(tile t: grid){
    t.draw();
}
```

Then within each tile object, I am checking to see if the mouse is within that tile:

```
void mouseMoved(){
      float isoX = mouseX / (width-(width/2));  
      isoX = isoX * ((cos(radians(30))-sin(radians(0))));      
      float isoY = mouseY * (cos(radians(60))-sin(radians(0)));
      if(isoX > posX && isoX < posX+20
      && isoY > posY && isoY < posY+20)
      println(getX()+", "+getY());
  }
```

For reference posX and posY are the positions given to each tile when setup in an arraylist at the beginning of the program.

It may just be my maths, but could anyone help with this?

Comment: Have you tried just using mouseX and mouseY without performing any math on them and then checking to see if the `isoX` and `isoY` coordinates fall within a particular grid position?

Comment: The `posX` and `posY` is being checked per tile (it's part of the tile class). With the current code it's part-working e.g. it's correctly returning x positions at the top of the grid, but also below the grid meaning the translation is slightly skewed. I really think it's just the maths but it's been giving me a headache.

Comment: Have you tried just using `mouseX` and `mouseY` as `isoX` and `isoY` respectively?

Comment: `mouseX` and `mouseY` return only the actual screen co-ordinate regardless of translations.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to wrap the translate method inside push and pop Matrix:

```
pushMatrix();
translate(width-(width/2), 0);
//draw here
popMatrix();
```

In fact once you do translation the defaults for mouse coordinates are translated with that specific transform so they return the transformed values upon invocation.

Comment: Hi Tod, Everything is wrapped in push and pop matrix methods. Processing still returns the screen pixel coordinate untranslated.

Comment: Well, Could you please update your question with maybe a smaller or sub-part, but complete in it's own, of the source code with the problem in it, so that the problem can be traced after running it in processing IDE.